# What does it take to massively parallelize a flow matrix equation?

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, numerical-algorithms

I'm not a scientist nor am I math savvy, but I'd like to know what the feasibility would be of solving a shallow water flow equation using massive parallelization. CUDA and stuff like that.

Im referring to this paper: http://www.3di.nu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Stelling_ice_2012.pdf

Would such an algorithm be suitable for parallel computing?

Comment: Parallelizing that is the only hope for numerical solution, yes. Numerical solution of PDEs is one of the principal uses of massively parallel computers, yes. This general tyoe of problems has (and still is) area of active research, yes.

Comment: 1) What is a "shallow water equation"? 2) "CUDA and stuff like that" is offtopic here. You want to ask such questions on [SO] or [scicomp.SE], depending on the focus of the specific question. 3) Whether an algorithm is amenable to parallel computer is impossible to tell without looking at the algorithm. Don't expect people to read the paper; please sketch the algorithm in pseudocode. 4) Note that CPU and GPU programming require completely different paradigms. It's unlikely that a CPU-based algorithm translates easily to GPUs. Do you exclude massive CPU parallelization per se?

Comment: 5) Parallel algorithms/programming still require advanced skills on both conceptual and technological level (if the problem does not parallelize trivially/embarrassingly).

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll do my best to improve this post soon or move it to Computational Science